# deploy django project to webfaction and stuck with TemplateDoesNotExist

Tags: python, django, apache, deployment, webfaction

I'm trying to deploy django project to webfaction and stuck with the problem that the server does not see my templates folder

```
PROJECT_DIR = os.path.dirname((os.path.dirname((os.path.dirname(__file__)))))

    TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(PROJECT_DIR,'templates'),
   )
```

python path in httpd.conf :

```
 python-path=/home/wadadaaa/webapps/promo_site/myproject:/home/wadadaaa/webapps/promo_site/lib/python2.7
```

And i have exception:

```
Exception Type: TemplateDoesNotExist
Exception Value: index.html 

Django tried loading these templates, in this order:
Using loader django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader:
/home/wadadaaa/webapps/promo_site/templates/index.html (File does not exist)
```

any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

When deploying to WebFaction I add the project's parent directory to the python_path:

```
python-path=/home/wadadaaa/webapps/promo_site:/home/wadadaaa/webapps/promo_site/myproject:/home/wadadaaa/webapps/promo_site/lib/python2.7
```

If you're using Django 1.5.x, a common way I "map" directory paths like TEMPLATE_DIRS, STATIC_ROOT, etc, is to use a function to compute those. This is especially useful if you work on more than one machine, or in a group, where the path to these files is going to vary per-developer:

```
# settings.py
import os

def map_path(directory_name):
    return os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),
        '../' + directory_name).replace('\\', '/')
...

TEMPLATE_DIRS = (
    map_path('templates'),
)
```

This is a convenient way to map your templates directory, given a project structure of:

```
my_app/
    my_app/
        __init__.py
        settings.py
        ...

    a_module/
        __init__.py
        models.py

    templates/
        layouts/
            base.html

        index.html
        ...
```

Comment: Did you restart the Apache instance?

Comment: yes of course, but did you mean to add this line to the httpd.conf?

Comment: Yes, you would add that extra path to the httpd.conf

Comment: No, I made ​​changes to the existing path

Comment: Apologies, that's what I meant.

Comment: 502 – Bad Gateway

The page you requested is currently unavailable. Please try again later.

If you are the website owner, please see Error: 502 Bad Gateway documentation for more information and possible steps to resolve the problem.

Comment: Did you get an email with the exception? Tail the error log and see what's up.

Comment: rolled back, there are still ideas, why not seen templates?

Comment: I've added an example of how I map paths to templates that works across platforms, which hopefully will help you out. I deploy all of my applications to WebFaction, and the httpd.conf example and this function are what I use in production successfully.